# HTML inserting ghost list elements

Tags: html

I've created a list that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>one<li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four<li>
</ul>
```

But when I view this page in my browser, two extra list elements are inserted, making the code look like this:

```
<ul>
<li>one</li><li>
</li><li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li><li>
</li></ul>
```

Does anybody know how this could possibly happen? I tried removing all other code and all stylesheets/scripts, but that doesn't solve the problem either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am flagging to close because "*this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error.***"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a closing brackets on your first li and last li

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```